# Conditions for WebGL in android WebView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, webgl

Background: 
I have two apps written for Android using Xamarin.

Both try to use a WebView to display webGL content.

Both compile against Android 6, Minimum 4.0.3, target version 6.0.

Both are run on a Samsung S7.

One app (the 'newer') can show webGL content, the other claims webGL is disabled.

**My question is: What conditions could break webGL in a WebView?**

Some things I've already tried to rule out:

- Compile SDK version
- Target Android version
- Activity base class (both are FormsAppCompatActivity)